# How to combine IF statements and Vlookup

Tags: excel

I am trying to combine IF statements and Vlookup.

Below is the formula I tried, it works when the result of the VLOOKUP is 0, but if it not `0` then I need the result of the V-lookup to be displayed.

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$D$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B9&"'!"&"A:J"),10,False)=0,"Leave"),"--")
```

Kindly correct me where I went wrong also just wanted to let you know I am new to excel.

Comment: `=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$D$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B9&"'!"&"A:J"),10,False)=0,"Leave",VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$D$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B9&"'!"&"A:J"),10,False)),"--")`

Comment: I copy pasted the same but it shows error in the formula.

Comment: Comments sometimes adds unseen characters.  try typing the formula from scratch, not copy, paste.

Comment: Thanks for the tip !! It worked !! Also the word "false" I typed it in CAPS "FALSE"- can this be the error !!!

Comment: No, there were a couple unseen characters in the comment.  putting `False` Excel will automatically change it to `FALSE`

Comment: I appreciate the help !!